# Положение слайдера не соответствует заданному

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockoutjs

Есть такой код, который отслеживает [изменения положения слайдера](https://jsfiddle.net/6L1xhh06/).
Однако при первом запуске, ползунок находится не на заданной позиции. В чем может быть проблема?

```
var viewModel = {
    id: ko.observable("slider-new"),
    min: ko.observable(10),
    max: ko.observable(100),
    value: ko.observable(20) //начальное положение слайдера
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score -1):

не уверен, что хорошее решение, однако, как я понял, jquery-плагин запускается до выполнения knockout, попробуй через setTimeout выполнять его после

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?